# Is it undefined behavior to dereference a *mut T cast to *mut ManuallyDrop<T>?

Tags: rust, undefined-behavior, unsafe, raw-pointer

According to the docs, `ManuallyDrop<T>` is a zero-cost wrapper. Does that mean I can dereference a raw pointer to `ManuallyDrop<T>` casted from a raw pointer to `T`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ManuallyDrop` is [declared as `#[repr(transparent)]`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.30.0/src/libcore/mem.rs#L950-L956):

```
#[stable(feature = "manually_drop", since = "1.20.0")]
#[lang = "manually_drop"]
#[derive(Copy, Clone, Debug, Default, PartialEq, Eq, PartialOrd, Ord, Hash)]
#[repr(transparent)]
pub struct ManuallyDrop<T: ?Sized> {
    value: T,
}
```

`#[repr(transparent)]` is [described as](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.27.0/unstable-book/language-features/repr-transparent.html):

> The attribute can be applied to a newtype-like structs that contains a single field. It indicates that the newtype should be represented exactly like that field's type, i.e., the newtype should be ignored for ABI purpopses [sic]: not only is it laid out the same in memory, it is also passed identically in function calls.
>
> [...]
>
> `PtrWithCustomZst` is also represented exactly like `*const Foo`

I believe that it is safe to perform this transformation.

---

The real question is *why* would you want to do this? Having a pointer to a `ManuallyDrop` structure seems rather pointless. If you have a pointer to a `T`, the underlying value won't be dropped to start with. If you convert the pointer to a reference (while ensuring you uphold the rules of references), the reference won't drop the underlying value either.